# Color in string must imported (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, colors

I have a color defined in a server and which is imported.
This is the String which calls it :

```
String color = xStrings.getString(ColorStrings.ConfigColor.Configs.BAY_TEXT_COLOR);
```

The string contains the next value : 
    #FFFFFF

This is the line in which it's must be called :

```
String finalString = xVay + "<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + xBay + "</font>" + yVay+ "<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + yBay + "</font>" + zVay + "<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + zBay + "</font>" ;
```

As you can see above it's hardcoded, how could i tell the HTML that it must take the value of BAY_TEXT_COLOR ?  I have tried various solutions but none worked, also did a research through stackoverflow but didn't find any answer to this.

Somebody has an idea?

Comment: `"<font color='"+color+"'>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String finalString = xVay + "<font color='" + color + "'>" + xBay + "</font>" + yVay+ "<font color='" + color + "'>" + yBay + "</font>" + zVay + "<font color='" + color + "'>" + zBay + "</font>" ;
```

This does not work?

Comment: Worked like a charm, i am not a big fan of HTML, and also not a big fan of implementing it in android :) But thanks mate this worked and i have learned something :) Will mark as correct answer in 5 minuts

Answer (score 2):

Another way to got is with `String.format()` method:

```
String format = "%2$s<font color='%1$s'>%3$s</font>%4$s<font color='%$1s'>%5$s</font>%6$s<font color='%1$s'>%7$s</font>";
String finalString = String.format(format, color, xVay, xBay, yVay, yBay, zVay, zBay);
```